# How to clear this issue in this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here i select Apartment,Villament,Row House, for my requirement multiselect no need to make again one more array, how can do this, i am tying like this but i can't get the exact answer if any one knows means tell me

```js
function createJSON() {
    jsonObj = [];
  jsonObj12 = [];
    $("input[class=email]").each(function() {
        var email = $(this).val();
  var items = [];
  $('.Check1:checked').each(function(){
   items.push($(this).val()); 
    
   });
        item = {}
        item ["email"] = email;
  
  jsonObj12.push(items);
  item ["multiselect"]=jsonObj12;
  

        jsonObj.push(item);
    });

    console.log(jsonObj);
}

// Geting aswer like this
Array[1]
0:Object
email:"a@gmail.com"
multiselect:Array[1]
0:Array[3]0:"Office Space"
1:"Apartment"
2:"Villament"

// Requirement aswer like this 
Array[1]
0:Object
email:"a@gmail.com"
multiselect:Array[3]
0:"Office Space"
1:"Apartment"
2:"Villament"
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Email<input title="Title1" type="text" class="email" >
<!--<input title="Title2" type="text" class="email">
<input title="Title3" type="text" class="email">-->



<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Office Space"> Office Space        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Apartment"> Apartment        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Villament"> Villament        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Individual House"> Individual House       
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Row House"> Row House
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn-submit" value="submit" onClick="createJSON()">
```

Comment: Where is the PHP code for your `php` tag?

Comment: You can edit the tags @Federkun

Comment: @JayBlanchard You could also add the `javascript` tag, while you're at it.

Comment: So can you @CharlotteDunois ;)

Comment: Please don't do `$("input[class=email]")`.  Use `$('input.email')` instead.  Avoid attribute selectors when possible.

Comment: ya sorry i put wrong tag

Comment: Why is it bad advice?  Class selectors are more efficient than attribute selectors.  An attribute can be on pretty much on any element.  The browser can't inherently scope it down like classes/ids/tagNames.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I know that, I edit tags whenever I see the need. It's just unnecessary to let 500 users make tags edit if one could make all in one.

Comment: any one update my requirement answer

Comment: How are they more efficient @Taplar? I've not seen any benchmarking which indicates better efficiency.

Comment: That's why I winked @CharlotteDunois ;)

Comment: @JayBlanchard quick test. https://jsfiddle.net/9p52fvgr/1/  Granted this fiddle is a very small page with far fewer elements that it has to investigate for the attribute selector compaired to a normal page, which would exacerbate the issue.

Comment: Fascinating @Taplar. I'll run some other tests on this to test the veracity of the claim. For a normal page with a set of selectors I would doubt highly you would see any efficiency loss. It's all about balance and we, as developers, must be careful when focusing on micro-optimizations. Personally I think that you *should* use the class selector here, but for readability, not efficiency.

Comment: Sure, the efficiency loss is most likely unnoticeable.  However, in the grand scheme of incorporating best practices into our coding practices it's always good to be aware of what things will allow the libraries to optimize best vs forcing them to do things the hard way (in this case forcing jQuery to use sizzle instead of trying to shortcut to a lower level method like getElementsByClassName).

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all "multiselect" values then assign it directly to object key in your final result:

```js
function createJSON() {
   result = [];
    $("input[class=email]").each(function() {
        var email = $(this).val();
        var text = $(this).siblings('input.text').val();
  var items = [];
  $('.Check1:checked').each(function(){
   items.push($(this).val()); 
   });
      result.push({email: email, text: text, multiselect: items})
    });
    console.log(result);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Email<input title="Title1" type="text" class="email" >
<!--<input title="Title2" type="text" class="email">
<input title="Title3" type="text" class="email">-->
Text <input title="Text1" type="text" class="text" placeholder ="Text 1">


<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Office Space"> Office Space        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Apartment"> Apartment        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Villament"> Villament        
 </li>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Individual House"> Individual House       
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" style="padding-left: 4px; padding-right: 4px;">
 <li style="color: #333; font-size: 85%;">
 <input type="checkbox" class="Check1" name="listing_type[]" value="Row House"> Row House
</div>

<input type="button" id="btn-submit" value="submit" onClick="createJSON()">
```

Comment: Mr @areq Al-Zubaidi thank you its working fine ,now i want add one more field like mobile , that is text filed how can do , pls update your answer

Comment: @KaniR here you go

Comment: Sorry i can't understand

Comment: which part you don't understand ?